# Trying to save image with a http path in Asp.Net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to save a image with a `http` path?
In my case all images are stored in a different location from the one of my website.

My code throws an exception that says "URI formats are not supported" when I run below code

```
string fileLocation = "http://img.servername.com";

Bitmap bmp = GetImage();

bmp.Save(Path.Combine(fileLocation,"a.jpg"));
```

Comment: Is it another server that you control? If so, you can simply create a network location and save it that way. The problem is that you're dealing with I/O tools over a protocol they are not designed to work with (HTTP). However, traditional I/O works over LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save to a local directory and file not a URL.

```
string fileLocation = @"c:\mydirectory";

Bitmap bmp = GetImage();

bmp.Save(Path.Combine(fileLocation,"a.jpg"));
```

You will also need to ensure your web application has write privileges to the location. Note that uploading files and saving them to your server can present significant security issues and vulnerabilities which are beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply, its easy to save images on your local drive becoz you have full right, but in my case i want to save on a webserver other that my website webserver

Comment: Actually by default IIS does not have rights to write files to the local disk but that issue aside, `BitMap.Save` does not support writing to a URI. You will need to connect to a service endpoint on your destination server utilizing a different method. `WebClient.UploadFile()` is likely your easiest approach but it will only upload files from your local disk which ideally you can avoid (rather uploading directly from an in-memory stream.)

Answer (score 0):

It's just not that simple.

I think you have 2 possibilities.

You can send it via `ftp` or via `http`.

If you want to send it via `http`, that server has to have implemented a method that accepts a `POST` request with a `byte array` parameter.

From you web application, you have to convert your image to a `byte array` and use it to make a `POST` request to that specific action.

Via `ftp` you need the credentials and here is a little demo from msdn docs:

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

// Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

response.Close();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx